# How can I update polymer binding without reinstantiating property?

Tags: binding, polymer

I have the following situation:
A custom element which renders items from an array

```
<dom-module id="shopping-cart">
 <template>
  <style>
    :host {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
  <template is="dom-repeat" items=[[cartItems]]>
    <tr>
      <td>[[item.name]]</td>
      <td><span>[[item.quantity]]</span> <small>[[item.uom]]</small></td>
      <td><span>[[item.cost]]</span> <small>lei</small></td>
    </tr>
  </template>
 </template>
<script>
  (function() {
  'use strict';

  Polymer({
    is: 'shopping-cart',

    properties: {
      cartItems: {
        type: Object,
        value: []
      }
    }
  });
})();
</script>
<!-- And this is the container -->
<template is="dom-bind" id="app">
  <shopping-cart cart-items="[[cartItems]]"></shopping-cart>
</template>
```

I am manipulating the `app.cartItems` object based on some events. I expected the binding to update when altering the array, but it doesn't. When pushing new elements, or removing others, the changes are not reflected in the `shopping-cart` element. I tried to fire the `cart-items-changed` event by hand but that still doesn't help. The only thing that seems to cause the binding to refresh is assigning a new array altogether for the `app.cartItems` property, but that doesn't seem right. I feel like I'm missing some simple step but I can't figure out which one. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See

- https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#array-binding
- https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#array-mutation

> Every Polymer element has the following array mutation methods available:
>
> - push(path, item1, [..., itemN])
> - pop(path)
> - unshift(path, item1, [..., itemN])
> - shift(path)
> - splice(path, index, removeCount, [item1, ..., itemN])

You need to use one of these for Polymer to get notified about changes.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I was able to combine info from both links to get it right. I used `app.push("cartItems", item)` to get the items to appear in the cart, and for mutating the properties of the objects inside the array, I used the same approach, with the `path`: got the index of the item, `var path = "cartItems." + itemIndex; app.set(path + ".quantity", product.quantity); //[ ...]` and updated every property individually.